# scrapy - item loader - mysql

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am starting to learn scrapy. I want to use an item loader and write some data to MySQL. The code below works perfectly fine when I use argument "TakeFirst()" for the output processor in items.py. However, I need to get all the entries to MySQL, not only the first. When I use argument "MapCompose()" instead, I get the following MySQL-related error message:

> Error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

How do I need to modify my code to write all entries into MySQL?

test_crawlspider.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from tutorial.items import TestItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class TestCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test_crawl"
    allowed_domains = ["www.immobiliare.it"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.immobiliare.it/Roma/case_in_vendita-Roma.html?criterio=rilevanza"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="no-decoration button next_page_act"]',)), callback="parse_start_url", follow= True),
    )

    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=TestItem(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('price', '//*/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/strong/text()')
        l.add_xpath('rooms', '//*/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/span[4]/text()')
        return l.load_item()
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join


class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
    price = scrapy.Field(
        output_processor=TakeFirst(),
    )
    rooms = scrapy.Field(
        output_processor=TakeFirst(),
    )
```

pipelines.py:

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import hashlib
from scrapy.http import Request
from tutorial.items import TestItem    

class MySQLPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='XXX', passwd='YYY', host='localhost', db='ZZZ')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, test_crawl):  
        print item
        return item
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (price, rooms) VALUES (%s, %s)", (item['price'], item['rooms']))       
            self.conn.commit()

        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
            return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an item per entry in the listing, something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class TestCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test_crawl"
    allowed_domains = ["www.immobiliare.it"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.immobiliare.it/Roma/case_in_vendita-Roma.html?criterio=rilevanza"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="no-decoration button next_page_act"]',)), callback="parse_start_url", follow= True),
    )

    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        for selector in response.css('div.content'):
            l = ItemLoader(item=TestItem(), selector=selector)
            l.add_css('price', '.price::text')
            l.add_css('rooms', '.bottom::text, .bottom span::text', re=r'.*locali.*')
            yield l.load_item()
```

I've changed a bit the selectors so that you can check other possibilities (while learning about scrapy), but maybe this isn't the information you wanted to extract.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `string` values to mysql, that's why `TakeFirst()` works, because it transforms the list that you get inside your loader, and only gets the first element (this is the normal procedure, because it normally gets staff like `['myvalue']` on which case is perfectly ok to get the first element only).

Now if you want to input a list into your database, say `['a', 'b', 'c']` you need to define how to serialize it to a string, for example:

```
 'a;b;c' # join the list elements with ';' -> ';'.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

This is something you need to define because later when querying from the database, you'll have to desearilize it accordingly:

```
 'a;b;c'.split(';') -> ['a' ,'b', 'c']
```

To use my example you could use something like this on your loader:

```
class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
    price = scrapy.Field(
        output_processor=Join(';'),
    )
    rooms = scrapy.Field(
        output_processor=Join(';'),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While this writes the data to MySQL, I would prefer to have each element from the list in a separate row.